# serve regarding question

Tags: sentence-choice

When I was introducing people to a dish, I'd like to express it can be eaten cold or hot, but I want to use the word serve express the same meaning, do I say this dish can be ***served*** chilled or hot or can ***serve*** chilled or hot?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, the dishes don't serve themselves, but are served by a person. So someone can **serve** the dish hot, but the dish can only **be served** hot.